# Which combination of global/local sudo/notsudo for which node.js npm install package?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'd like to install packages like these on MacOSX, but interested in Windows or Linux versions too:

```
npm install express
npm install swig
npm install mongodb
npm install consolidate
npm install http-auth
```

If I call npm without sudo, some of them will fail:

```
Error: EACCES, open '/Users/me/.npm/cookie/0.1.2/package.tgz'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open '/Users/me/.npm/cookie/0.1.2/package.tgz']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/me/.npm/cookie/0.1.2/package.tgz',
npm ERR!   parent: 'express' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator
```

If I install with sudo, the files end up wherever my current directory is, and there under node_modules.

If I use the -g command, I get the access problem.

If I use the -g with sudo, it installs, but the node app cannot find the packages:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
```

Am I missing something important? What is the correct way to install these packages? (I was told, that installing globally should be preferred, so that all apps are always linked to the most up-to-date package version, so if that makes a difference, please let me know)

Answer (score 0):

Node.js will traverse folders upwards until it finds your package, so you can install all in your home folder:

```
cd ~
npm install express
```

Comment: Show us the error please

Answer (score 0):

From the `npm help 5 npm-folders`man page:

- Local  install (default):
   puts stuff in `./node_modules` of the current package root.
- Global install (with `-g`):
  puts stuff in `/usr/local` or  wherever  node is installed.
- Install it locally if you're going to `require()` it.
- Install it globally if you're going to run it on the command line.
- If you need both, then install it in both places, or use npm link.

The only time I used `sudo` was the install of `nw` because I wanted it to be linked in `/usr/bin`. After the invoke with `sudo` I ran into similar Errors, because `root` as owned my `~/.npm/_locks` directory.

Every `install` ran into Error, until I `chown` `~/.npm` and `~/.npm/_locks` back to my user.

Follow the instruction of man page and check `~/.npm` everytime you `sudo`.